# Python Split String dont work

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, split, pyserial

No matter what I try, this string is not split.

```
def funktion():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM5',115200)
    b = str("Das ist ein Test")
    a = str(ser.readline().decode())
    b.split(' ')
    a.split('s')
    print (a)
    print (b)
```

[image]

Comment: Please use plain text to show the output of your code instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String aren't mutable, so you have to re-assign those:

```
b = b.split(' ')
a = a.split('s')
print(a)
print(b)
```

See more on **[Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)** SO question and in [**that**](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/) article.

Answer (score 1):

the `split` function does not change the string in-place. it returns a new string. you must do `tokens = b.split(' '); print(b)` instead.